# Using groupby to create new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Python DataFrame (df) which includes time series data (days of the year) for various countries.    Timeseries is a column of the df, and is repeated by country.  The file looks something like this:

| Country | Date | Total Vaccinations | People Vaccinated Per Hundred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Israel | 1/1/21 | 100 | .001 |
| Israel | 1/2/21 | 104 | .002 |
| ... | ... | ... | .004 |
| Israel | 2/1/21 | 150 | .010 |
| USA | 1/1/21 | 0 | .000 |
| USA | 1/2/21 | 50 | .001 |
| ... | ... | ... |  |
| USA | 2/1/21 | 500 | .05 |

etc,etc. Assume this is the case for 200+ countries.

I wish to create a new df which will contain data for a single feature (say "Total Vaccinations") by countries, using Date as the index.

So the engineered df becomes (selecting "Total Vaccinations"):

| Date | Israel | USA | U.K. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 1/2/21 | 104 | 50 | 25 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2/1/21 | 150 | 500 | 250 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to achieve this -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> d = ['1/1/21','1/2/21','1/3/21','1/4/21'] * 3
>>> v = [100,104,103,205] * 3
>>> c = ['USA','Isreal','UK'] * 4
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':c,'Total_Vaccinations':v,'Date':d})
>>> df
   Country  Total_Vaccinations    Date
0      USA                 100  1/1/21
1   Isreal                 104  1/2/21
2       UK                 103  1/3/21
3      USA                 205  1/4/21
4   Isreal                 100  1/1/21
5       UK                 104  1/2/21
6      USA                 103  1/3/21
7   Isreal                 205  1/4/21
8       UK                 100  1/1/21
9      USA                 104  1/2/21
10  Isreal                 103  1/3/21
11      UK                 205  1/4/21

>>> pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Date'],values=['Total_Vaccinations'],columns=['Country'])
>>> pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.columns.droplevel()
>>> pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
>>> pivot_df
Country    Date  Isreal   UK  USA
0        1/1/21     100  100  100
1        1/2/21     104  104  104
2        1/3/21     103  103  103
3        1/4/21     205  205  205
>>>
```

You can also drop the `Country` column further

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
#create DatetimeIndex
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

#create subset by list of countries
need = ['Israel','USA']
df = df[df['Country'].isin(need)]
```

Comment: your suggestion for setting the index does not appear to address duplicate dates which occur within each country subgroup.

Comment: @GPB - Then not understand what need, can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: - apologies, I've clarified my question after thinking more carefully about what I'm after.  Seems to be a 'groupby' solution, but I'm not well versed. 
Appreciate any further help!